# Character conversion when inserting a data.frame into another one

Tags: r, dataframe, types, character

```
d = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=6,ncol=3))
names(d) = c("a","b","c")
```

Insert vectors into `d` works as I expected

```
d[1,] = c(1, "Hello", "P")
d[2,] = c(2, "Hello", "Q")

print(d) 
     a     b    c
1    1 Hello    P
2    2 Hello    Q
3 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
4 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
5 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
6 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```

I would have expected the same result when trying to insert a data.frame into `d`

```
sub_d = data.frame(
    a = 1:2,
    b = rep("Hello",2),
    c = c("P","Q")
)

d[1:2,] = sub_d
d

   a  b  c
1  1  1  1
2  2  1  2
3 NA NA NA
4 NA NA NA
5 NA NA NA
6 NA NA NA
```

But for some reason characters get converted into integer and this is true even if I specify `d$a = as.character(d$a); d$c = as.character(d$c)` before hand.

I suppose one could iterate over each row of a data.frame to insert the constituent vectors. Is there another way to insert a data.frame into another one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What may be tripping you up is that `data.frame` converts strings into factors by default. The following will insert the new data frame more like what, I think, you want it:

```
d = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=6,ncol=3))
names(d) = c("a","b","c")

sub_d = data.frame(
  a = 1:2,
  b = rep("Hello",2),
  c = c("P","Q"), stringsAsFactors=F
)

d[1:2,] <- sub_d
d

   a     b    c
1  1 Hello    P
2  2 Hello    Q
3 NA  <NA> <NA>
4 NA  <NA> <NA>
5 NA  <NA> <NA>
6 NA  <NA> <NA>
```

The integers you're seeing are the unlabeled factor levels. If (for example) `d$b` was already defined as a factor, with labels, and `sub_d$b` was a factor with the same labels on the same levels, then you'd have no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Add `stringsAsFactors` to your data.frames gives you the desired output:

```
d = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow=6,ncol=3), stringsAsFactors = F)
names(d) = c("a","b","c")    

sub_d = data.frame(
  a = 1:2,
  b = rep("Hello",2),
  c = c("P","Q"), stringsAsFactors = F
)

d[1:2,] <- sub_d
d
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check the structure of your dataframe `sub_d` with `str` you'll see the columns `a` and `b` are factors.

```
str(sub_d)

#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#$ a: int  1 2
#$ b: Factor w/ 1 level "Hello": 1 1
#$ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "P","Q": 1 2
```

You can convert those columns to character with `lapply`

```
sub_d[-1] <- lapply(sub_d[-1], as.character)
```

and then if you do

```
d[1:2,] <- sub_d
```

you get

```
d
#     a     b    c
#1    1 Hello    P
#2    2 Hello    Q
#3 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
#4 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
#5 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
#6 <NA>  <NA> <NA>
```